# Displaying a single array item from JSON in PHP (NODE.JS and EXPRESS API)

Tags: php, json, node.js, express

I have Express running on a custom node API that breaks down a large JSON into bite sized chunks for mobile usage.

One of the section goes through a mass of items and returns only one of them. However the returned data is still wrapped in [ .. ] which makes working with it tough.

My NODE.JS code snippet that deals with my routed request

```
app.get('/ppm/detail/operators/:operatorCode', function (req, res) {
    var with_operatorCode = ppm.RTPPMDataMsgV1.RTPPMData.OperatorPage.filter(function (item) {
        return item.Operator.code === req.params.operatorCode;
    });
    res.json(with_operatorCode);
});
```

so if you access the url

```
http://(domain)3000/ppm/summary/operators/25
```

the following data is returned

```
[
  {
    "code": "25",
    "keySymbol": "",
    "name": "First Great Western",
    "Total": "577",
    "PPM": {
      "rag": "G",
      "text": "94"
    },
    "RollingPPM": {
      "trendInd": "+",
      "displayFlag": "Y",
      "rag": "G",
      "text": "97"
    }
  }
]
```

How can I break that object out of the [ .. ] so it is not returned as an array object and only shows as

```
 {
    "code": "25",
    "keySymbol": "",
    "name": "First Great Western",
    "Total": "577",
    "PPM": {
      "rag": "G",
      "text": "94"
    },
    "RollingPPM": {
      "trendInd": "+",
      "displayFlag": "Y",
      "rag": "G",
      "text": "97"
    }
  }
```

Alternativly, how can I work with the [ .. ] object in PHP? When I am trying to echo it using

```
$operatorJSON=file_get_contents("operator.json");
$operator=json_decode($operatorJSON);

echo $operator->PPM->text;
```

It errors if the JSON has the [ ]

I suspect it is being treated as an array object

UPDATE : I tried to flatten the array

```
app.get('/ppm/detail/operators/:operatorCode', function (req, res) {
    var with_operatorCode = ppm.RTPPMDataMsgV1.RTPPMData.OperatorPage.filter(function (item) {
        return item.Operator.code === req.params.operatorCode;
    });

    var obj = arr.reduce(function(x, y, i) {
        x[i] = y;
        return x;
    }, {});

    res.json(obj(with_operatorCode));
});
```

but the object returned is still in [ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly , i think the most easy way is use the index to get the element in array

```
res.json(with_operatorCode[0]);
```

Comment: My mouth is open with how simple.. AND how obvious that was. Thank you for this amazing and simple answer! Genius!

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the `[`foo`]` denotes that it is an array.

You could address the item as [0], but that is more likely to cause an error, if no item exists in the filter:

On the php side:

```
$operator=json_decode($operatorJSON);
echo $operator[0]->PPM->text;
```

On the Node side:

```
res.json(with_operatorCode[0]);
```

The smarter thing to do would be to handle it as an array:

```
$operator=json_decode($operatorJSON);
if (is_array($operator) && count($operator))
{
   echo $operator[0]->PPM->text;
}
```

Or, if filter may give you more than one:

```
$operator=json_decode($operatorJSON);
foreach ($operator as $op)
{
   echo $op->PPM->text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for the amazing detail, I used the answer above which matched with your NODE solution, but upvoting as this contains some amazing detail and I really appreciate this, and apologies for accepting the earlier and simple answer and not yours

Answer (score 0):

Try for this:

```
 function toObject(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    obj[i] = arr[i];
  obj rv;
}
```

Comment: The object returned is still in [ ], added my attempt based on your code to the OP above